# Increment index on multidimensional array using AJAX in cakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, cakephp

first sorry if my question isn't clear at all.

So, I have an app with Transaction module in cakePHP. That module (at least) have 3 chained dropdowns like this Supplier > Products > Packages. User choose Supplier, then in products select box show the result only products from that selected supplier. So do the packages, options will show when choose products.

Simply, I use [this](http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2011/11/dynamic-select-box-with-cakephp-2-0/) reference to do first chain. It works. But when going into Packages, it isn't easy as first lol. Why? Because the second form where Products and Packages element have more complex dimensional array from first. In first form (Supplier element), I fetch its data with `$this->request->data['Order]['supplier_id']`

But in second form, the data that will passed from Ajax like `$this->request->data['OrderDetail'][$index]['product_id']` where the index in second form have increment number.

Example:

```
<select id="Product0" name=data[OrderDetail][0][product_id]></select>

<select id="Product1" name=data[OrderDetail][1][product_id]></select>

<select id="Product2" name=data[OrderDetail][2][product_id]></select>
```

Then in my controller,

```
public function functionName() {
    $product_id['index'] = $this->request->data['OrderDetail']['index']['product_id'];
}
```

**EDITED**

Sorry, forgot to post my ajax code.

```
<?php
$this->Js->get('#OrderSupplierId')->event('change', 
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'products',
        'action'=>'gpbs'),
    array(
        'update'=>'.OrderDetailProduct',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(
            array(
                'isForm' => true,
                'inline' => true)
            )
        ) 
));
```

How can I pass the dynamic index too in AJAX??
So, when it sent to controller, data from every "form element" will match.
Thanks, and sorry for my bad language (and description)

Comment: Can you please post the ajax code that makes the request?

Comment: Sorry forget. Already post it :)